# Draw a scaled Bitmap to the Canvas?

Tags: java, android

The following code defines my Bitmap:

```
Resources res = context.getResources();

mBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.background);

// scale bitmap
int h = 800; // height in pixels
int w = 480; // width in pixels
// Make sure w and h are in the correct order
Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBackground, w, h, true);
```

... And the following code is used to execute/draw it (the unscaled Bitmap):

```
canvas.drawBitmap(mBackground, 0, 0, null);
```

My question is, how might I set it to draw the scaled Bitmap returned in the form of `Bitmap scaled`, and not the original?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Define a new class member variable:
`Bitmap mScaledBackground;`
Then, assign your newly created scaled bitmap to it:
`mScaledBackground = scaled;`
Then, call in your draw method:
`canvas.drawBitmap(mScaledBackground, 0, 0, null);`

Note that it is not a good idea to hard-code screen size in the way you did in your snippet above. Better would be to fetch your device screen size in the following way:

```
int width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
int height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
```

And it would be probably better not to declare a new bitmap for the only purpose of drawing your original background in a scaled way. Bitmaps consume a lot of precious resources, and usually a phone is limited to a few MB of Bitmaps you can load before your app ungracefully fails. Instead you could do something like this:

```
Rect src = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth() - 1, bitmap.getHeight() - 1);
Rect dest = new Rect(0, 0, width - 1, height - 1);
canvas.drawBitmap(mBackground, src, dest, null);
```

Comment: your answer worked for me, but subtracting 1 from width and height in arguments was displaying a line (from another bitmap at the background) at right and bottom of the displayed bitmap, removing -1 worked fine.

Comment: I know this is an older post now.  But for Android 7.0+, you may not be able to rely on the full display width/height when in split screen mode.  So, for anyone using this solution, you should keep that in mind.

Comment: would this way draw bitmap very slow?

Answer (score 0):

To draw the scaled bitmap you want save your scaled bitmap in a field somewhere (here called `mScaled`) and call:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(mScaled, 0, 0, null);
```

in your draw method (or wherever you call it right now).