# Improve performance of Canvas.drawBitmap() on android

Tags: android, algorithm, optimization, canvas, bitmap

Going with the time I try to implement view pager in my tile based game -  and swiping is janky.   I performed necessary performance measures like suggested by @romangui ,   and found out that redrawing my gaem field takes about 48 msec (way too long) - and I already flattened layout, eliminated overdraw have my custom layout managers etc.

I discovered that drawing one tile  on GN takes about 0.600 msec - way too long for all 81 tiles. Time is actually spend on `Canvas.drawBitmap(...)`

Any ideas how to improve performance?  I have only  6 different bitmaps,   they are loaded once and reused.  ARGB_8888. Of course they to not necessarilly match actual displayed size.

Would I get better performance if I pre render them for actual display size after my layout was measured?

Or shall I bite the bullet and pre render one big bitmap with my game state just for scrolling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be sure that you do not make Android to use scaling of the images while drawing.

Try to use previously scaled images, as in [Draw a scaled bitmap to the canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407089/draw-a-scaled-bitmap-to-the-canvas)

Comment: Derfinitely worth to try,  and I can do it  while doing custom layout.

Comment: OK, this improved  performance a lot (single glyph went from 0.6 msec to 0.2), so drawing performance is almost perfect.  I will accept the ansewer unless somebody comes with even better solution by tomorrow evening